# Android-gps listener

Tags: android-location

I use this code to get gps sensor data.

```
mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, mlocListener);
```

Why does my gps icon continuously turn on and off?

Comment: if you mean the blinking of the icon, then i guess, your phones GPS-Sensor searches the satellites.

Comment: the programm returns the location and the speed correctly, but the icon still blinking. I think something happens with the time=2000 but i don't know exactly.

Answer (score 0):

2000 milliseconds is approximatley 0.0333333 seconds. In your code, you have requested for location updates every 0.0333333 seconds.

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, mlocListener);
```

This means for that the GPS doesn't always have to be updating itself. Thats why the GPS icon continuously turns on and off.

Comment: 2000 milliseconds are exactly 2 seconds.

Comment: Im sorry, but thats not true.